# Thin line between horizontal <img> and <div>

Tags: html, css

I have a thin white line between a black image and a div with a black background on a page with the body background set to white.  I have tried setting `border: 0 !important`amongst other things but I just can't get rid of it.

[image: site header]

Is there anyway of removing this?

Comment: Is the line on the image itself?

Comment: `vertical-align : top` on the image?

Comment: please add an [mcve] to your question.  With your rep, you should know better by now

Comment: Yes, sorry should've added code etc. my bad, in a panic and rush.  It was of course on my image d'oh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, try `border: none;` on both the `div` and the `img`. Also double check that it's not actually part of the image. It may also be a `margin` on the `div`. Finally, try stringing the `div` and `img` immediately next to each other with no whitespace.

```
 <img><div>
```

instead of

```
 <img>
 <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the image to "display:block;" with CSS. If the Line is not in your image or in your DIV, it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
img{
vertical-align:middle;
}
```